# Descriptografar senha PASSWORD_HASH

Tags: php

Boa tarde! Pessoal, eu preciso exibir para o cliente a senha que ele digitou e não 60 caracteres Criptografados. Como eu posso fazer esse procedimento? Abaixo está o código de recuperação de senha que eu criei. Contudo, ele exibe apenas os 60 caracteres e não a senha que foi digitada pelo cliente.

Estou usado o password_hash, default

```
$email_recuperado = $_POST['email_recuperar'];
$consultaEmail = $verde_conexao->query("SELECT * FROM verde_cadastro WHERE email = '{$email_recuperado}'");
$rows = $consultaEmail->num_rows;
$senhaGlobal = $consultaEmail->fetch_assoc();

if($rows == 1):

    echo $senhaGlobal['senha'];

endif;

$verde_conexao->close();
```

Resultado do $senhaGlobal: `$2y$10$s8eqpQimDaz4e.aUkCIaheP5rD0hgULSQBdyk/9pSGQQysOGNkoMW`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação do [`password_hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), em tradução livre:

> `password_hash()` cria um novo hash de senha usando um forte algoritmo de hash unidirecional.

Ênfase em **unidirecional**. Generalizando, não faz sentido usar uma criptografia para senha que pode ser descriptografada por questões de segurança. Caso precise comparar senhas, compare usando [`password_verify`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

No caso de **recuperação de senha**, você deve fornecer ao usuário um modo de criar uma nova senha, e não de ver a sua senha antiga.

Comment: Compreendi. Muito explicativo a sua resposta. Obrigado.